# WCF using Transport always attempts to use HTTPS when I don't want it to

Tags: wcf, https, transport, credentials

I keep getting the following error "Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http]."  This started because I went to Basic Transport Authentication by adding:

```
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="secureBasic">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
```

After googling the common fix seemed to be the following code, but I had no success with it:

```
<baseAddressPrefixFilters>
  <add prefix="http://mywebsiteurl"/>
</baseAddressPrefixFilters>
```

Still, nothing works.  All I want is to use basic http authentication on a non-https connection.  I have configured absolutely nothing and it appears by default WCF wants to force a HTTPS connetion.  Anyone run into this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you tell WCF to use transport security mode, you must use a transport protocol that supports secure communication. HTTP doesn't support secure communication because it's a plaintext protocol (anyone that intercepts your communication can simply read what is being transmitted). HTTPS does support secure communication so your only option for a `webHttpBinding` with transport security is to use HTTPS (which you can configure in IIS).

[Here](http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2006/07/31/890.aspx) is a blog post describing your error and how to solve it using `TransportCredentialOnly`. It's about `basicHttpBinding` but the same holds for your `webHttpBinding`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want only transport level authentication (= Basic authentication) but you don't want transport level secure communication (= HTTPS) you have to set security mode to TransportCredentialOnly.